# Marker Interfaces, Implementing vs Importing

Tags: java, oop

If I have a simple marker interface (contains no methods) which contains constants used throughout my application, is there any difference between a class importing the interface and actually implementing the interface?

Interface:

```
public interface MyConstants {
    String constant1 = "constant1";
    String constant2 = "constant2";
}
```

Implementing:

```
public class MyClass implements MyConstants {
    public MyClass(){
        System.out.println(constant1);
    }
}
```

Importing:

```
import common.constants.MyConstants
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(){
        System.out.println(MyConstants.constant1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the *constant interface* anti-pattern at work.

Comment: This is not a Marker interface, but a constant interface.

Comment: Not to mention if you want convenient, non-scoped access, you could always use  static import.  I would say that implementing an interface simply to get constants is bad form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement it would be an anti-pattern:

> In the Java programming language, the constant interface pattern
>   describes the use of an interface solely to define constants, and
>   having classes implement that interface in order to achieve convenient
>   syntactic access to those constants. However, since constants are very
>   often merely an implementation detail, and the interfaces implemented
>   by a class are part of its exported API, this practice amounts to
>   putting implementations details into the API, which is considered
>   inappropriate. [1][2] In general, collecting system constants into
>   classes independent of behaviour, might create a poor object-oriented
>   design, because it is often a sign of low cohesion. It is for these
>   reasons that implementing constants interfaces is considered to be an
>   anti-pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface

*And regarding marker interface you can check it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface).*

Answer (score 1):

I would only call it a marker interface if it is intended to actually *mark* classes as having a particular property, in which case they must implement the interface for `instanceof` checks to work. If it's just intended as a convenient place for constants, then I wouldn't call it a marker interface and I wouldn't have any classes implement it, since it's adding something to the implementing class's public face that is just an implementation detail.